# Vritual host in windows 8 apache xampp

Tags: php, windows, apache, laravel-5

I am trying to config virtual host in windows 8 ,i installed Apache in port 8080 the below are my config files so far i tried,still i am getting 404 error

**httpd-vhost conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>        
        ServerName design.com
        ServerAlias www.design.com
        DocumentRoot  "C:/xampp/htdocs/proj_des/public/"
        <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/proj_des>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>        
        DocumentRoot  "C:/xampp/htdocs"
        ServerName localhost

</VirtualHost>
```

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 8080
```

**host in system32**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       www.design.com
```

Comment: Double quote `C:/xampp/htdocs/proj_des` restart xampp

Comment: @ifconfig if put localhost it show 404 if i give localhost:8080 only it works  ,same like www.design.com also

Comment: @HarishKarthick Yes. Your server is spawned on port `8080`, and therefore will only be available for access on port `8080`. By default, if you don't specify a port, the browser will try to connect on port `80`. That is why you don't get a response when you go to `localhost` and not `localhost:8080`.

Comment: @ifconfig ok how to overcome this problem ,for  that we specify the port in vhost

Comment: @HarishKarthick Does my answer work for you? If so, please indicate that it did by accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is spawned on port `8080`, and therefore will only be available for access on port `8080`. By default, if you don't specify a port, the browser will try to connect on port `80`, the HTTP port. That is why you don't get a response when you go to `localhost` and not `localhost:8080`

To change the port the server is listening on, replace `8080` with `80` anywhere where the code specifies which port to listen on:

*httpd-vhost.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>        
        ServerName design.com
        ServerAlias www.design.com
        DocumentRoot  "C:/xampp/htdocs/proj_des/public/"
        <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/proj_des>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>        
        DocumentRoot  "C:/xampp/htdocs"
        ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

*httpd.conf*

```
Listen 80
```

Comment: But i need to run some other port except 80 bcoz my iis currently running on it

Comment: Then you have to specify a port when you visit the page in your browser. There's no way around it.

Comment: Is there is any way to specify the port in virtual host or some config file

Comment: Yes, I just showed you how to do it. But the problem is the browser, not the server.

Comment: The browser will ***ALWAYS*** default to port `80` unless you specify otherwise. Choose between which server you need to be on port `80`.